# Inplicit Function to Explicit

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Can someone explain me, how can I transform this implicit function into that explicit? I thought it was impossible and resolved the exercise as it was an implicit, but as you can see in the solutions of the exercise they can transform it!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the implicit function theorem makes no promises as to being able to represent the implicit function explicitly (in terms of elementary functions, that is). However, there's also nothing to imply that it couldn't be done in specific cases. Here, for example, you have a quadratic equation in $x$, admitting the standard solution.

Comment: But how can I transform the implicit to explicit? In this case, at least?

Comment: Don't you know $x=(-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac})/(2a)$ for $ax^2+bx+c=0$?

Comment: As mentioned, the quadratic equation $a(t)x^2 + b(t)x + c(t)=0$ has the two (usually distinct, and possibly complex) solutions $\frac{1}{2a(t)}\left(-b(t)\pm\sqrt{b(t)^2 - 4a(t)c(t)}\right)$.

Comment: Oh ok, it was to easy I was thinking to far ahead to see the basic!

Comment: How am I supposed to choose between the solution with + or - before the square root?

Comment: @FranciscoGonçalves that part depends on context. Here, for example, you're looking for an implicit function such that $x(t_0)=x_0$ for some $t_0,x_0$, so that should give you the answer.